# Where are form elements rendered in Drupal 7? I'm looking for why the sixth item in a select option list doesn't get rendered

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, drupal-7

I have Drupal 7.58 site where there's a select list with 15 items that come from an entity reference. When I put a debugging statement into form_type_select_value in includes/form.inc, the whole array of items is there, so I know the query is working, and the form element should be built correctly.

But when the select list is display, the sixth element goes missing. I've found a short term way to circumvent this, by adding a dummy sixth item, but that's not going to fly in the long term.

What I need to know is where does it go after form_type_select_value?

edit: More info

This is happening in an Entityform where the field type is Entity Reference and the Widget is Select List. In Manage Fields under Entity Selection, I select an entity called Store, in Simple mode. There are 15 Stores, and these are sorted by the Title property, sorted in the Ascending direction.

When I sort in Descending direction, a different item is missing, but it's always the 6th from the top.

I've debugged it up to the point where the data comes in, before it's rendered, and it's all there in the outgoing array.

Comment: Are you sure the referenced entity (the 6th) still exists and accessible? This could be access/permission related. Also, could you be more specific how you are using that entity reference select list? more information will be useful.

Comment: I've added more info. The entity is definitely there before it gets to the html, and you can make a different item disappear just by adding more items at the top, or by reversing the sort order. I hope I've added enough extra info.